# Heroku Redis connections Limit, what it means?

Tags: heroku, redis

I'm in doubt about what this connection limit means, i don't know if it refers to simultaneously connections from process or connections that you make at each time(For example my app connect one process to redis, that process finished the work, and i have spended one connection), anyone can clarify it to me? Thank you guys very much.

Comment: I would like to know this as well, how long does a connection stay active can it be expired?